# Including an Enumerate Environment within a "Fancy" Quote

Tags: errors, enumerate, font-encodings, renewcommand, quotation

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}

\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent{#1}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyquote{A quote.}{Author}

\fancyquote{
\begin{enumerate}
\item A quote.
\item Another quote.
\end{enumerate}}{Author}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The first `fancyquote` is fine; however, the second containing the `enumerate` environment is produced with an error message: [image]

QUESTION: Does anyone have an idea what may be causing the error? There is also a slight change in the font, undoubtedly as a result.

Thank you.

Comment: `\noindent{#1}\\ ` is just completly wrong, the `\noindent` before `\begin{eumerate}` does not stop indentation just forces a spurious empty paragraph, and `\\ ` after `\end{enumerate}` forces a line break where there is no line so gives the error you show

Comment: you could replace `\\*` by `\par\nopagbreak`

Comment: why `\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont` rather than `\sffamily` ?

Comment: the (slight???!!!) change of font from roman to sans serif is not due to the error.  `\fancyquote` does not group the font change so all the document after the first quote is in sans serif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\sffamily---}}% long???
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}

\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \par{\parindent=0pt #1\par}\nopagebreak
  \hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\textit{\sffamily\textbf{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyquote{A quote.}{Author}

\fancyquote{
\begin{enumerate}
\item A quote.
\item Another quote.
\end{enumerate}}{Author}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks David Carlisle.